# Error creating table with foreign key Laravel

Tags: laravel, mariadb

This is my first table migration file :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('produits', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('nom',255)->unique();
        $table->string('photo')->default('default.png');
        $table->longText('description');
        $table->float('prix');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('categorie_id');
       
        $table->foreign('categorie_id')->refrences('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This is my second table migration file :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('nom',255)->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This is the error i'm getting :

```
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'produits' already exists (SQL: create table `produits` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `nom` varchar(255) not null, `photo` varchar(255) not null default 'default.png', `description` longtext not null, `prix` double(8, 2) not null, `categorie_id` bigint unsigned not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

I tried both : `php artisan migrate` , `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Comment: You have to create a table before you can reference it as a foreign key. Try running the script to create categories first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove the tables from database and before you run the migrations again, make sure **categories** migration is created first.
If you have created **produits** migration first, it won't work because when migrations are run, the **produits** table is created first and it will not find the referenced table which does not exist yet. Therefore,  the foreign key constraint will not be created.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Almost, you can try `php artisan migrate:fresh`, this will remove all tables and create new ones.

Does your migration have the drop method?

```
 public function down()
{
    statement('DROP TABLE categories');
}
```

Comment: Still getting same error.

Comment: Does your migration have the drop method? edited answer above.

Comment: yes this exists in my migration  ,public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }